# Refactor controller to follow sandi's rule of five lines

Tags: ruby-on-rails, refactoring

I'm trying to follow sandi metz' rules of five lines per method, 
do you have any ideas of good ways to turn a basic controller create
and update method to five lines of code.

```
  def create
    @article = @blog.articles.build(article_params)
    if @article.save
      flash[:success]   = "Article saved!"
      redirect_to blog_article_path(@blog, @article)
    else
      flash.now[:error] = "Unable to save article. Kindly correct the errors before trying again."
      render :new
    end
  end

 def update
    if @article.update_attributes(article_params)
      flash[:success] = "Article updated!"
      redirect_to blog_article_path(@article.blog, @article)
    else
      flash.now[:error] = "Unable to update article. Kindly check the errors and correct them before trying again."
      render :edit
    end
  end
```

Any advice, comments & suggestion will be very much appreciated :D

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks great and this template is followed by rails scaffolding as well. Also, if you remove the if-else condition statements from consideration, your method follows the five lines per method rules.

Comment: oh, this gives me confidence with my code. But still i'd like to know how those who strictly follow the rule would do this.